# Question regarding "integration by parts"

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm reading about "integration by parts", and I have a hard time understanding why in the below example they do the procedure 3 times. Or maybe better put, when do you know that you have to do integration by parts more in order to be finished?
[Function to be integrated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1qm2.png)
[Step by step how the book does it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPget.png)

Can't you just simply say that you are finish integrating, when we obtain the integral for the last "remainder" part, which in this example was xe^2x in part **?

Comment: As you highlighted in that text: when we see that on time it has simplified the integral, why not trying it a couple of times more?

Comment: But it wouldent have been correct to stop at *?

Comment: Not if you want to solve the integral. Case closed.

Comment: @Economics_student: $(*)$ still has the term $-\frac32 \int x^2 e^{-2x}\, dx$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it was hard for me to see why more integration was needed. Yes i can see that the integration sign was still there in * and **, but how do you know you are done on a pure mathematical basis?

Comment: You're done when you want to be done. There's no "pure mathematical" basis for what consists of an answer, as that depends on what the problem is asking. For most exercises though, that is when there are no longer more integrals in your expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to "When do you stop integrating?" is "When you have something you know how to integrate".

Do you, inherently, know what $\int x^3 e^x dx$ is? It doesn't normally appear on a table of standard integrals. We do know how to find $\int x^3 dx$ and $\int e^x dx$, though, and so the aim of using IBP is to hopefully make use of these integrals we *do* know somehow.

If we apply IBP in the direction shown in the textbook, we find that we're left with a term like $\int x^2 e^x dx$, and while it still isn't something we can read off a table, we notice that we've reduced the $x^3$ to $x^2$ and intuitively we can see that if we repeat the process we're likely to keep reducing the exponent of $x$ - from $x^3$ to $x^2$ to $x$ to just a constant, and once we do that we know we'll be left with just the nice simple integral $\int e^x dx$.

Now we *could* apply IBP the other way around - treating $x^3$ as the $g'$ and $e^x$ as the $f$. But what we find if we do that is that we end up increasing the exponent of the polynomial term - we go from $x^3$ to $x^4$, and if we continue in that direction we're just going to get increasingly more complicated integrals that we don't know how to approach.

A lot of integration is like this - applying techniques like substitution and integration by parts to transform an ugly integral into something more familiar. Sometimes, it takes a mix of experience and trial-and-error to get to the answer.

Comment: Nice answer - mine isn't perfect but I like your explanation.

Comment: Just a follow question. Can't you also say that you are finish integrating, when we obtain the integral for the last "remainder" part, which in this example was xe^2x in part **?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. Typically the aim is to find a closed form of the integral, or at least to transform the integral into something that can be used elsewhere, so if you're asked to find the integral of $x^3 e^x$ you're not "finished" until you get an expression with no integral signs in it.

Comment: Yes, i meant ofc. if im asked to find a closed form of the integral. So you are basically saying yes to my question, if i understand you correctly? Meaning that if i get a function, like X^3*e^x, and are asked to find a closed form of the intergral to that fuction, then im first finished when the last "reminder part", i.e xe^2x in step/part ** has found its integral?

Comment: Yes, once you reach an expression that has no integral signs in it then it's fair to say you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we can differentiate $f$, and we can integrate $g$. Integration by parts exchanges the problem of computing

$$\int fg dx\tag 1$$

with that of computing

$$-\int f'G dx\tag 2$$

plus an extra term, where $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$. This can be repeated to get to

$$(-1)^n\int f^{(n)}g^{(-n)} dx\tag 3$$

again plus some other terms, where $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-fold derivative of $f$, and $g^{(-n)}$ is the $n$-fold antiderivative of $g$.

So, applying this rule $n$-times is useful precisely when $(3)$ happens to be easier than $(1)$.

Some cases when this happens:

1. If $f$ is a polynomial, then $f^{(n)}=0$ for some $n$, and $(3)$ vanishes and is therefore easier than $(1)$.
2. If $f$ satisfies a differential equation, e.g. $f=\sin x$, then $(1)$ and $(3)$ may be related.

The example $\int x^3e^{2x}dx$ is one where $f=x^3$ is a polynomial, thus integrating by parts 4 times will give zero, so the whole answer is just the `extra terms' I glossed over above. Moreover, $g=e^{2x}$ is easily integrable, which is another requirement for this to work. In situation 1. the process can be done very quickly as is explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2I-_SV8cwsw&ab_channel=blackpenredpen).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have an power and a transcendental function (namely a trigonometric/exponential function like $\sin x$ or $e^x$), each time  you apply IBP, the power in $x$ reduces, and you will get a simpler function in $x$ until you reach a constant, leaving you with a simple transcendental function.

For your case, $x^3$ can be differentiated to $3x^2$, then $6x$, then $6$ and then zero, while $e^{2x}$ will integrate to $\frac {1}{2} e^{2x}$ each time.  Thus, you have to carry out IBP several times and add your prior results until you get to the simplest function without a power in $x$, usually the constant.

\begin{matrix}
u = x^3 & dv = e^{2x} \\
du = 3x^2 & v = \frac {1}{2} e^{2x}\\
\end{matrix}

$$\therefore uv - \int v \ du = \frac {1}{2} x^3 e^{2x} - \int 3x^2 e^{2x} \ dx$$

\begin{matrix}
u = 3x^2 & dv = e^{2x} \\
du = 6x & v = \frac {1}{2} e^{2x}\\
\end{matrix}

$$\therefore uv - \int v \ du = \frac {1}{2} x^3 e^{2x} - \frac {3}{2} x^2 e^{2x} - \int 3x e^{2x} \ dx$$

\begin{matrix}
u = 3x & dv = e^{2x} \\
du = 3 & v = \frac {1}{2} e^{2x}\\
\end{matrix}

$$\therefore uv - \int v \ du = \frac {1}{2} x^3 e^{2x} - \frac {3}{2} x^2 e^{2x} +  \frac {3}{2} e^{2x}- \int \frac {3}{2} e^{2x} \ dx$$

Since the final integral is simple ($\int \frac {3}{2} e^{2x} \ dx$) it'll be $\frac {3}{4} e^{2x}$, so our complete function is $$\frac {1}{2} x^3 e^{2x} - \frac {3}{2} x^2 e^{2x} + \frac {3}{2} x e^{2x} - \frac {3}{4} e^{2x} + C$$ and if we wanted to clean it up we'd get $$\frac {1}{2} e^{2x} (x^3 -3x^2 +3x -3/2) + C$$

Comment: but when you look at *** you are left with 1/2e^2x after the intergral sign, how is that a constant?

Comment: When you continue integrating a function with a power in it, especially an integer power, at one point you'll differentiate the power function to one that does not have a power, i.e. you will have a constant term.  If you take a look at what you have, you have a simple function $\int \frac {1}{2} e^{2x} \ dx$ that you can easily integrate because you no longer have a function of $x$ preceding it.